Is the formula known? and can we generalized for higher dimensions?
In this configuration as follows, we have a nice formula:
$$\cos(\varphi)=\frac{OF.OE+OB.OC}{OF.OB+OE.OC}$$
Is the formula known? and can we generalized for higher dimensions?

